# NetBeans Deployment Error in JSF project

Tags: java, jsf-2

I was developing a JSF project and it could be deployed then. But when i added some packages with some classes to the project, the console says that the project can not be deployed. I am unable to identify the problem. Any help as to where might be the problem would be greatly appreciated.

I use Netbeans IDE 6.8, glassfish v3 Domain. Mojarra 2.0.2

```
Copying 1 file to /root/NetBeansProjects/jsfscrb/build/web/WEB-INF/classes
compile:
compile-jsps:
In-place deployment at /root/NetBeansProjects/jsfscrb/build/web
Initializing...
deploy?path=/root/NetBeansProjects/jsfscrb/build/web&name=jsfscrb&force=true failed on GlassFish v3 Domain
/root/NetBeansProjects/jsfscrb/nbproject/build-impl.xml:888: The module has not been  deployed. 
BUILD FAILED (total time: 54 seconds)
```

glassfish domain v3 tab

```
SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool 60 at position41
SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool -26 at position42
SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool -70 at position43
SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool -99 at position44
SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool 60 at position45
SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool -23 at position46
SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool -119 at position47
SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool 60 at position41
SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool -26 at position42
SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool -70 at position43
SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool -99 at position44
SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool 60 at position45
SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool -23 at position46
SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool -119 at position47
INFO: Instantiated an instance of      org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: nullID: /root/NetBeansProjects/jsfscrb/build/web/ CLASSES: [class carePack.User,  class carePack.jobQueue, class carePack.homebean, class carePack.JobMonitor, class carePack.UserWizard, class carePack.login_bean, class carePack.JobMonitor$1ff2, class carePack.Job, class org.mit.jobSubmit.FileUpload, class org.mit.jobSubmit.ARJob, class org.mit.jobSubmit.NormalJob, class org.mit.jobSubmit.LeaseJob, class org.mit.login.logauth, class org.mit.login.NewUserReg, class org.globus.LeaseCreation.Client.CancelLease, class   org.globus.LeaseCreation.Client.ExtLeaseClient, class     org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.rhClient, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.AxisrhStatus, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.setJobStatus, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.HashrhClient, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.JobHelper, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.HashClient, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.AxisrhDiscovery, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.AxisrhClient, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.getJobStatus, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.AxisJobStatus, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.rhClientBackup, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.JobStatus, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.JobClient, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.deleteJob, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.getPool, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.WFClient, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.WorkFlow, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.Job, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.CreateJob1, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.resInfo, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.WorkFlowClient, class org.globus.RequestHandler.Client.ClientWorkFlow, class javaxmlinterface.JavaXml]

SEVERE: PWC1420: Error invoking ServletContainerInitializer     org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6180: Unable to initialize TldScanner
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanTlds(TldScanner.java:287)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.onStartup(TldScanner.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5279)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1933)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1605)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.list(FileDirContext.java:989)
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.listBindings(FileDirContext.java:419)
    at org.apache.naming.resources.ProxyDirContext.listBindings(ProxyDirContext.java:555)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.listCollectionPaths(ApplicationContext.java:1452)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResourcePathsInternal(ApplicationContext.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResourcePaths(ApplicationContext.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResourcePaths(ApplicationContextFacade.java:218)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.processTldsInFileSystem(TldScanner.java:482)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.processTldsInFileSystem(TldScanner.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.processTldsInFileSystem(TldScanner.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.processTldsInFileSystem(TldScanner.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.processTldsInFileSystem(TldScanner.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.processTldsInFileSystem(TldScanner.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanTlds(TldScanner.java:283)
    ... 42 more

SEVERE: PWC1306: Startup of context /jsfscrb failed due to previous errors
SEVERE: PWC1305: Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: PWC2769: Manager has not yet been started
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:892)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5383)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5211)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1933)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1605)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:         org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6180: Unable to initialize TldScanner
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5216)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1933)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1605)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException:     PWC6180: Unable to initialize TldScanner
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5287)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5190)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6180: Unable to initialize TldScanner
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanTlds(TldScanner.java:287)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.onStartup(TldScanner.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5279)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.list(FileDirContext.java:989)
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.listBindings(FileDirContext.java:419)
    at org.apache.naming.resources.ProxyDirContext.listBindings(ProxyDirContext.java:555)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.listCollectionPaths(ApplicationContext.java:1452)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResourcePathsInternal(ApplicationContext.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResourcePaths(ApplicationContext.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResourcePaths(ApplicationContextFacade.java:218)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.processTldsInFileSystem(TldScanner.java:482)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.processTldsInFileSystem(TldScanner.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.processTldsInFileSystem(TldScanner.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.processTldsInFileSystem(TldScanner.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.processTldsInFileSystem(TldScanner.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.processTldsInFileSystem(TldScanner.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanTlds(TldScanner.java:283)
    ... 42 more
WARNING: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:     org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6180: Unable to initialize TldScanner
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:     org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6180: Unable to initialize TldScanner
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1933)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1605)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

SEVERE: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:     org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6180:      Unable to initialize TldScanner
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:     org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6180: Unable to initialize TldScanner
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

INFO: true
INFO: jobid initialized;135
```

**EDIT**
I have found where the problem was and overcome that.
The problem precisely was " the packages i have added to the project, were containing not only .java files but also .class files."

When I deleted all the .class files from the packages. The project is again deployed...

Thank you for trying to help me friends. I thought posting this might be helpful to someone with the same problem.

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest JDK, or reinstall NetBeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-13918). Try replacing glassfish/modules/jsp-impl.jar with [new version](http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/glassfish/web/jsp-impl/2.2.2-b06/jsp-impl-2.2.2-b06.jar).

Comment: the deployment problem occurred was not related to this bug mate. It was occurred because there was some class files inside the package.